# DSE upgrade deleted datastax-agent conf folder

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I'm running a 3-node cluster in AWS. Yesterday, I upgraded my cluster from DSE 4.7.3 to 4.8.0.

After the upgrade, the datastax-agent service is no longer registered and the /usr/share/datastax-agent/conf folder has been removed.

PRE-UPGRADE:
`$ ls -alr
total 24836
drwxrwxr-x   3 cassandra cassandra     4096 Aug 10 14:57 tmp
drwxrwxr-x   2 cassandra cassandra     4096 Aug 10 14:56 ssl
drwxrwxr-x   2 cassandra cassandra     4096 Sep 28 15:14 doc
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra 25402305 Jul 14 18:55 datastax-agent-5.2.0-standalone.jar
drwxrwxr-x   2 cassandra cassandra     4096 Sep 28 18:23 conf
drwxrwxr-x   3 cassandra cassandra     4096 Sep 28 18:13 bin
drwxr-xr-x 118 root      root          4096 Oct  2 18:02 ..
drwxrwxr-x   7 cassandra cassandra     4096 Oct  7 19:03 .`

POST-UPGRADE:
`$ ls -al
total 24976
drwxr-xr-x   3 cassandra cassandra     4096 Oct  5 20:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 114 root      root          4096 Oct  5 18:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 cassandra cassandra     4096 Oct  5 20:45 bin
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra 25562841 Sep 10 20:43 datastax-agent-5.2.1-standalone.jar`

Also, /etc/init.d/datastax-agent file has been deleted. I don't know how I'm supposed to start/stop the service now.

Can I restore the files from the rollback directory? What effect will that have?

Comment: What method of installation where you using? Packages, tar ball, standalone installer? What OS version is this?

Comment: standalone installer `DataStaxEnterprise-4.8.0.2015091812-linux-x64-installer.run` `$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty`

Comment: I'm not sure why the .run installer would blow away your agent install. Have you tried clicking the fix button in OpsCenter to re-install the agent? Otherwise you can use the package manager to install it.

Comment: On further digging, it appears that the 4.8 installer moved the whole folder structure from `/usr/share/datastax-agent` to `/usr/share/dse/datastax-agent/`

Comment: That folder under dse is just there as a fallback. The new installer is using the package install internally (using it's directory structure) to allow opscenter to properly manage the agent. It seems that that install failed... What happens when you try a dpkg install manually with the included package? Do you have the log file? Can you share that with me?

Comment: http://filebin.ca/2IGZsbHoX1sD/bitrock_installer_4676.log

Comment: Sorry for the delay, that last comment was hidden behind the "show more comments". Looking at it now.

Comment: Any chance we can hook up directly?

Comment: @sdelmas - absolutely what's the best way to contact you? We're in the Startup program - Clutch Holdings. I might be listed in there. My name is Mike J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case what happened was that the dpkg install found a preexisting /etc/init.d/datastax-agent file and only put /etc/init.d/datastax-agent.fpk.bak into place. A "sudo dpkg -P datastax-agent" followed by a "sudo dpkg -i /usr/share/dse/datastax-agent/datastax-agent_5.2.1_all.deb" fixed the issue. We had to first kill the already running agent processes and then do a service restart.

Will investigate how that could have happened... that's still a little bit of a mystery to me.